# Read an attribute "type" from a custom <section> node in web.config

Tags: asp.net, types, web-config, configsection

I've defined my own <sectionGroup> and <section> elements in the web.config.

One of the parameters that I need to specify via my custom <section> is a Type.

For example, I currently have

```
<variable name="stage" value="dev" type="System.String, mscorlib" />
```

and then in my implementation of `ConfigurationElement` I have

```
[ConfigurationProperty("type", IsRequired = true)]
public Type ValueType
{
    get
    {
        var t = (String) this["type"];
        return Type.GetType(t);
    }
    set
    {
        this["type"] = value;
    }
}
```

At runtime this throws the exception

> Unable to find a converter that supports conversion to/from string for the property 'type' of type 'Type'.

I've tried various things such as

- renaming the attribute to `valueType` (to avoid any clashes with a possible pre-configured attribute of the same name)
- specifying it simply as `"System.String"`
- changing the getter in the property to `return (Type) this["type"];`

but the exception is always the same.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("type", IsRequired = true)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(TypeNameConverter)), SubclassTypeValidator(typeof(MyBaseType))]
public Type ValueType
{
    get
    {
        return (Type)this["type"];            
    }
    set
    {
        this["type"] = value;
    }
}
```

The use of SubclassTypeValidator is not absolutely necessary, but most of the times you would use it ... I do at least.